# Drinking water after eating banana

Tags: human-biology

Why elders advice not to drink water after eating banana? Is there any science behind or is it a myth?

Found a [website](http://easyayurveda.com/2017/02/19/water-after-banana/) supporting this (so called?) myth.

Comment: Welcome to Bio. If this is a persistent and widely known myth please give a few sources.

Comment: @AliceD [I found this on internet](https://goo.gl/NHQVvd)

Comment: That is some random comment on a random site. We run a scientific stack and discussions of rumors are off topic.

Comment: @AliceD [disbelieve are accepted in stackexchange](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics)

Comment: here I have also heard elder people say we shouldn't drink water after eating melon or peach, but that is probably some myth that grew after someone got unwell after doing so

Comment: Added a link. Replace it if you find a better one.

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4134/drinking-after-eating-fruits-causing-belly-ache

Comment: Seems to be a cultural thing, like some religions not mixing meat & milk at a meal.  AFAIK the belief is unknown (or at least not common enough for it to have come to my attention) in the US or Europe.